# How is every binary relation BCNF?

Tags: database-normalization, functional-dependencies, bcnf

So, as part of my assignment, I have to prove that any relation with two attributes is in BCNF.

As per my understanding, if for a relation we have 3rd normal form and one non key attribute functionally determine key attribute, it violates the BCNF.

Say my relation consists of two attributes A1,A2

Scenario1(only one functional dependency)

```
A1 -> A2 (so A1 is the key, and A2 does not FD A1 : so no violation)
```

same applies for

```
A2 -> A1
```

But what if

```
A1->A2 and A2->A1
```

Here key can be either A1, A2. And the other non key attribute functionally determines the key.

Comment: What does your line of deductions have to do with what you are trying to prove? Also: You address a sufficient condition for BCNF not holding, but you don't address all cases of BCNF. So your resoning is unsound. Also: When some FDs hold others do. (Including trivial FDs). But you don't address that.

Comment: It's not true that every binary relation is in BCNF. Your instructors are ignoring that when {} is a determinant but not the CK, ie some attribute/subrow must have the same value in every tuple but there can be more than one tuple, then a relation isn't even in 2NF, since {} is a determinant that is a proper/smaller subset than any CK. (And it can be decomposed into 2 components, where one is the projection on the attribute/subtuple & the other is all the other attributes). What is true is that every binary relation where {} is not a determinant (or is but is CK) is in BCNF.

Answer (score 5):

In each functional dependency `X -> Y`, `X` and `Y` are sets of attributes. This requires special attention when either `X` or `Y` is an empty set<sup>1</sup>. So, in the example with only two attributes `A1` and `A2`, we have all the possible non-trivial dependencies:

```
1. {} -> {A1}
2. {} -> {A2}
3. {} -> {A1 A2}
4. {A1} -> {A2}
5. {A2} -> {A1}
```

All the other possible dependencies are trivial dependencies, i.e. the right set is a subset of the left set (for instance `{A1} -> {}`, `{} -> {}`, `{A1} -> {A1}`, `{A1 A2} -> {A1}`, etc.). We know that these dependencies always hold, so they are not considered in the definition of the normal forms.

**1. When empty sets are excluded from dependencies, the theorem is true**

Consider the dependencies 4 and 5. We have four possible cases:

```
1. Only 4 holds, so we have: {A1} -> {A2}
```

this means that `{A1}` is a candidate key (since from `{A1} -> {A2}` we can derive that `{A1}->{A1 A2}`), and the BCNF condition is satisfied since each dependency has a superkey as determinant;

```
2. Only 5 holds, so we have: {A2} -> {A1}
```

equivalent to the previous case, only the role of `A1` and `A2` is exchanged;

```
3. Neither 4 nor 5 hold (no functional dependencies),
```

so the BCNF is formally satisfied (since no dependency violates the BCNF); and, finally:

```
4. both hold, so we have {A1} -> {A2} and {A2} -> {A1}
```

also in this case the relation is in BCNF, since `{A1}` and `{A2}` are both candidate keys, since they determine all the attributes (simply put together 1 and 2 above).

**2. When we allow the empty set in the functional dependencies, the theorem is not true**

Consider a relation `R(A1, A2)`, with a cover `F` of the dependencies

```
F = { {}-> {A1} }
```

The meaning of `{} -> {A1}`, by recalling the definition of functional dependency, is that the column `A1` has a constant value. So we have a relation with two columns, one of which has always the same value. In this case the only candidate key is `{A2}`, since `{A2}+ = {A1 A2}`, with `{A1 A2}` a superkey, and the relation is not in BCNF since a non-trivial functional dependency (`{} -> {A1}`) has a determinant which is not a superkey.

---

<sup>1</sup> Note that in the scientific literature on the subject (as well as in books on databases) the possibility of empty sets in functional dependences is sometimes explicitly excluded (for instance, see: Tsou, Don-Min, and Patrick C. Fischer. “Decomposition of a Relation Scheme into Boyce-Codd Normal Form.” ACM SIGACT News 14, no. 3 (July 1, 1982): 23–29. https://doi.org/10.1145/990511.990513), while sometimes it is allowed, or not discussed.

Comment: Still sure would be nice if the definition of BCNF you are using were in this post. PS "since each dependency has a superkey as determinant" No. Since each non-trivial FD has a superkey as determinant. (How helpful it would be to have the definition you are using quoted to check/base your reasoning/justification on.) "they are not considered in the definition of the normal forms" This is just wrong, and a jumbling of what you actually mean, which you are not clearly saying, as I said in my last comment. (You keep seeming to want to take shortcuts, it just screws things up.)

Comment: for BCNF, is it required for LHS to be CK or SK is enough?

Comment: @Gourab Please ask (specific researched non-duplicate) questions in question posts, not comments. But a definition of BCNF is easily found including in SO Q&A. Also your question is not clear.

Answer (score 2):

```
For any relation to be in BCNF, the following must holds.

X → Y is a trivial functional dependency (Y ⊆ X).

X is a superkey for schema R
```

[Wikipedia link here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boyce%E2%80%93Codd_normal_form)

```
For Example, there is a relation R = {A,B} with two attributes. 
The only possible (non-trivial) FD's are {A}->{B} and {B}->{A}. 
So, there are four possible cases:

1. No FD's holds in R. {C.K = AB}, Since it is an all key relation it's always in BCNF.

2. Only A->B holds. In this case {C.K = A} and relation satisfies BCNF.

3. Only B->A holds. In this case {C.K = B} and relation satisfies BCNF.

4. Both A->B and B->A holds. In this case there are two keys {CK = A and B} and
   relation satisfies BCNF.

Hence, every Binary Relation (A relation with two attributes) is always in BCNF!
```

Comment: There can be more FDs that that, an FD is of the form set -> set. Also: It's not true that every binary relation is in BCNF, see my comment on the question.

Answer (score -1):

To prove any relation with two attributes is in BCNF.
**Rule For Boyce-Codd Normal Form:**

*A relation R is in BCNF if R is in Third Normal Form and for every FD,LHS is super key*

so if, A1 and A2 are the only attributes: A1 -> A2 and A2 -> A1 as functional dependencies, then in both functional dependencies, the left-hand side is a super key. Which satisfies the condition of BCNF.

Comment: There can be more FDs that that, an FD is of the form set -> set. Also: It's not true that every binary relation is in BCNF, see my comment on the question.